# Macbook Pro (Unibody): Trackpad requires too much force

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, trackpad

At first I thought my trackpad was broke and the clicker didn't work because it didn't always pick up my clicks. However, I've recently realized that is not the issue. The clicker requires a lot more force than I naturally use. **It works 100% of the time when I click it really hard and about %25 of the time when I click it with the natural amount of force for me.**

**Is there any way to make the clicker more sensitive?** I feel like I'm going to wear it out or possibly even break it if I have to click this hard all the time.

PS: I already know about tap to click but this does not help with highlighting text, login screen, etc. I need to make the actual clicker more sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the physical spring action of the button as well as the springs at the top of the trackpad that connect it to the unibody are adjustable and/or replaceable.

The parts are delicate and the set screw notoriously hard for beginning technicians to work on - even with official Apple parts and training.

I'd take it to Apple and if it is indeed different than the floor models in terms of force, you should be in great hands with them adjusting or repairing the hardware if it's not properly aligned or some foreign substance has worked itself into the gaps where the trackpad needs space to move.